# Can you serve up special content to an end-user based on IP or other identifiable data?

Tags: vpn, ip, user-tracking, deanonymization

Is it possible to serve up specific content to an end-user? For example, I know your IP address, and other device information. Can I use that to serve up certain search results on a search engine, certain videos on websites, and use that to target an individual with specific advertisements? Obviously I am not interested in carrying out such attacks, rather seeing if it is feasible.

Additionally, what information can identify a device if a VPN is in use?

Comment: You can use whatever info you would like from a client to serve different information.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a common practice. There are many ways to identify a user. Here's a few.

- user agent string in the request
- browser fingerprinting ([pantoclick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)
- IP address (country, region, ISP, known VPN ranges, blacklists, etc.)
- referrer header
- cookies
- previous history (look through your own logs to ID return traffic)
- [URL history harvesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394890/css-javascript-hacking-detect-visited-styling-on-a-link-without-checking-it)
- css fingerprinting

There's an almost endless way of identifying different users/clients. Serving different content is supported in pretty much every language/server.  It's the basis of dynamic web apps (facebook, Twitter, pretty much every interactive webpage)

Comment: Thank you for your response! For a specific example, could a black hat serve up certain pages/sites in search results on a search engine like Google, or would a company have to have corrupt software engineers for that to be possible?

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted what you were asking. It seems like you're talking about an attacker modifying a victims web traffic to/from a website the attacker doesn't control, is that what you meant?

Comment: You answered one part of my question, but I failed to communicate the other half of my question effectively! You answered the first part very well, and I greatly appreciate it! My follow-up question for you since you seem very knowledgeable was could an attacker modify search results? :)

Comment: If the search results were sent over an insecure channel (not using TLS a.k.a HTTPS) then yes, provided they had performed a Man in the Middle attack, and we're in line between the website and the victim, or on the victims network. Most traffic (including Google) is now encrypted (https) by default.

Comment: Thank you! My last question is could a private company like Google alter search results from the back-end? Or could a computer manufacturer display certain pages in the search section of a web browser. I.E typing in a few words and have it search through a database to display articles with certain topics (ex. bring up any pages mentioning certain topics, like babies or pizza)?

Comment: Google can and does sent personalised search results to you based off your account, location, and potentially other information. This is not a secret. A manufacturer could mess with search results, if they added malware to your company router before you bought it.

Comment: @BestReasonofWiseMen please edit your question with this new detail